# The error is "Call `Realm.init(Context)` before creating a RealmConfiguration"

Tags: android, realm

```
private void addAction() {

        String what = mInputWhat.getText().toString();
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

       Realm.init(getContext());

        RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);


        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        Drop drop = new Drop(what, now, 0, false);
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealm(drop);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Here whenever i don't create a contexet the app crashes 
but when i create a context using Realm.init(getContext()) the "Add it" button don't work[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvXln.png)

Comment: You should be setting that up in app initialization, and not a random method call somewhere deep in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You must init Realm in a class that extended from Application.see code below :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Realm.init(this);

        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("appName.realm")
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    }
}
```

after it u can call Realm class anywhere

don't forget add this line to your manifest application tag

> `android:name="com.example.MyApplication"`